# How to split a group in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have some voxels that I need to have grouped, so I place them in a container:

```
container.add(e);
```

and then add the container to the scene.
Is there a way now to split voxels again without creating them once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your `container` is an `Object3D`.

`Object3D.add( child )` automatically removes the child from its current parent.

So just do something like this:

```
var parent1 = new THREE.Object3D();
var child1 = new THREE.Object3D();
var child2 = new THREE.Object3D();
parent1.add( child1 );
parent1.add( child2 );
scene.add( parent1 );

var parent2 = new THREE.Object3D();
parent2.add( child2 ); // adding child to new parent
scene.add( parent2 );

console.log( 'parent1.children', parent1.children );
console.log( 'parent2.children', parent2.children );
console.log( 'scene.children', scene.children );
```

three.js r.58